# How to load a jpeg format picture in PyQt4 with QPixmap?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I use `print QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()` but in the output, there is no jpeg.
I searched the problem and find out that I need the `*.dylib` in `plugins/imageformats`.

So I moved it to `py2.7/site-packages/PyQt4`, but I still cannot load jpeg.

I use a python script, not py2exe, just `python test_pyqt.py`.

What should I do now?

Mac os x Mountain Lion 10.8.2, Python 2.7, PyQt4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477075/pyqt4-jpeg-jpg-unsupported-image-format

Comment: @andrean Hi,I have read that.But it tells me to reinstall the py2.7 as a admin.The py2.7 I currently use is installed when I install the os x .So I think it's installed as a admin.Actually I cannot find the "qt.conf" in my python dir....

Comment: try to add the library path manually: app = QtGui.QApplication([]) and then app.addLibraryPath('/path/to/plugins/imageformats')

Comment: @andrean still not working :(

Comment: try reducing the path tu just '/path/to/plugins'

Comment: you can obtain the path to qt by using the function app.applicationDirPath() somewhere near that path should be the plugins folder as well, pass that path to setLibraryPath. also check if there's actually a 'libqjpeg.dylib' file under plugins/imageformats folder

Comment: @andrean still not working. But i do find something that may be helpful. I search on the internet and find out that both jpeg and gif are supported by dynamic libs.But when I print supportedImageFormats, the gif is in the list while jpeg not. And the libqjpeg.dylib & libqgif.dylib are in the same folder....

Comment: @andrean And when I remove the all the dylib and print supportImageFormats, gif has disappeared!

Comment: if you scroll deep down there's someone who solved it on leopard, see his solution maybe helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885906/enabling-jpeg-support-for-qimage-in-py2exe-compiled-python-scripts

Comment: @andrean Fail again...I'm going mad! But I think my situation is different, cause I can get the GIF support, while all the dylib in the same folder.